# How can to obtain the transfer function of a bandpass digital filter?

Tags: bandpass, scipy, numpy, bode

I've been asked to: create a bandpass filter amplifier in python, determine the transfer function, graph the bode diagram, and print the highcut frequency, lowcut frequency, the bode constant and the transfer function.

I can choose the values.

So far, I've been able to create a bandpass filter and print the highcut and lowcut frequencies, but I don't know how to obtain and print the transfer function.

The code I'm using is below:

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqz


  def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
      nyq = 0.5 * fs
      low = lowcut / nyq
      high = highcut / nyq
      b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
      return b, a


  def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
      b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
      y = lfilter(b, a, data)
      return y


  # Sample rate and desired cutoff frequencies (in Hz).
  fs = 5000.0
  lowcut = 500.0
  highcut = 1250.0
  order = 6

  # Plot the frequency response.
  plt.figure(1)
  plt.clf()

  b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
  w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=2000)
  plt.plot((fs * 0.5 / np.pi) * w, np.abs(h),  'b')
  plt.plot(lowcut, 0.5*np.sqrt(2), 'ko')
  plt.plot(highcut, 0.5*np.sqrt(2), 'ko')
  plt.plot([0, 0.5 * fs], [np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5)], '--')

  plt.axvline(lowcut, color='k')
  plt.axvline(highcut, color='k')

  plt.xlim(0, 0.5*fs)
  plt.title("Filtro Pasabanda Respuesta en Frecuencia")
  plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
  plt.ylabel('Ganancia')
  plt.grid()

  # plt.legend(loc='best')

  # Creating the data for filteration
  T = 0.05
  nsamples = int(T * fs)
  t = np.linspace(0, T, nsamples, endpoint=False)

  x = (0.1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1.2 * t)) + (np.cos(2 * np.pi * 300 * t + 0.1)) + (np.sin(2 * np.pi * 600 * t + 0.11))

  plt.figure(2)
  plt.clf()
  plt.plot(t, x, label='Señal con Ruido')

  # Filtering and plotting.

  y = butter_bandpass_filter(x, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=6)

  plt.plot(t, y, label='Señal Filtrada')
  plt.xlabel('Tiempo (s)')
  # plt.hlines([-a, a], 0, T, linestyles='--')
  plt.grid(True)
  plt.axis('tight')
  plt.legend()

  plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
  plt.show()


  print('Frecuencias de Corte:')
  print(lowcut, 'Hz')
  print(highcut, 'Hz')
```

Please if you can help me out with the transfer function I will be really thankful. Also, if you can help me out with graphing  bode diagram and finding the bode constant, I would REALLY appreciate it.

Comment: well there's always the [cookbook](https://webaudio.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html) for a start.

Comment: The Python control package will do this quickly/ easy unless you are supposed to do it manually as a learning exercise?